# Access to the method without static

Tags: java

I have 2 class, class B and A

```
public class B

  private Car fiat;

  public boolean trueOrFalse() {
    return fiat.methodFromClassCar();
  }
```

In class A i want to use this result from this boolean, something like:

```
public class A

  public int xyz(){
    if (trueOrFalse()==true){
     doSomething(); 
    } 
  }
```

Always i making static all, but now i cant do this. Is there better way ?

Create a new object in class A:

```
Car cr = new Car();
```

and then using

```
cr.trueOrFalse();
```

is good way ? but what i code wrong here ?

Comment: You need to give a Car as parameter of xyz OR have a Car in attribute of class A

Comment: Extend the class B and use its methods!

Comment: Can you show us the real method's name to understand what you are trying to do? It's hard to understand your problem.

Comment: but this creating object is good ?

Comment: this class have 15k line ;/ and i cant extend

Comment: If a class has more than 500, and if really, 1000 lines, that's SURE that you split them, at work I never had more than 250 lines in a class, because one class = one job, you sure you can split your, very bad practice what you did

Answer (score 0):

You have different options :

-> have a `Car` as attribute of class A

```
public class A{
   private Car c;
   public int xyz(){
     if (c.trueOrFalse()){    //==true is 100% useless
        doSomething(); 
     } 
  }
}
```

call with `A test = new A(); /*then*/ test.xyz();  //c = new Car(); in constructor of A`

---

-> give to the method a `Car` as parameter

```
public class A{

   public int xyz(Car c){
     if (c.trueOrFalse()){   
        doSomething(); 
     } 
  }
```

call with `A test = new A(); /*then*/  test.xyz(new Car());  or Car c = new Car(); /*then*/test.xyz(c);`

Comment: but i want to use this same object, i can't use a new object

Comment: @desktop so use second option, in a Main in class, create an Object A and a object Car and use them